# Is there any way to add a template reference variable dynamically to the newly created DOM element in the TS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created a DOM element using `this.document.createElement('h1')` and I want the element to be added to section tag with a template reference variable (myTRF), something like below,

```
<section>
  <h1 #myTRF>This is my heading</h1>
</section>
```

Is there any way it can be achieved in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

First set some Id to section tag. (h1-section - id for section tag)

`var header = document.createElement("H1"); var text = document.createTextNode("This is my heading"); header.appendChild(text); document.getElementById("h1-section").append(header);`

Comment: I am not trying to add an ID, I am trying to add a template reference variable.

Comment: I am not sure but this is something you can try ...https://itnext.io/working-with-angular-5-template-reference-variable-e5aa59fb9af

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert DOM elements into a parent div having template reference variable and access it using @viewchildren : queryList dynamically.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div #div>#div is a template variable</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChildren("div") divs: QueryList<any>
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.divs.forEach(div => console.log(div));
  }
}
```

Reference :
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: There is no dynamic reference variable in Angular Template syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What's the use case. I think you might not even need template variable if you are creating it dynamically. How exactly you are planning to use that variable in rest of the template if it's not even defined at compile.

Comment: I am providing multi-lingual support in my web app and I have a h1 with a template reference variable. On language change, I delete the current h1 and want to replace it with the one having new language. I am using ngx-translate which resolves this issue but I also have a blast.js implemented which does not seem to work on just only using ngx-translate. Blast.js breaks your sentences into letters and you can add animation to it. I am using blast-vanilla npm library for that.

So, I am deleting the h1 on language change and try to replace it with dynamically placed h1 on it as a workaround.